# How to store a Coldfusion #variable# in MySQL and output the variable value (and not the variable name) from the database?

Tags: mysql, variables, dynamic, coldfusion

I'm running `Coldfusion8/MySQL 5.0.88`.

I have two tables in my database:

```
modules
textblocks
```

My site is running multiple languages, so I'm doing this at the beginning of every page to load textblocks from the database depending on user-selected language.

```
<cfquery datasource="#Session.datasource#" name="texte">
   SELECT *
   FROM textblocks
   WHERE lang = <cfqueryparam value = "#Session.lang#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="2">  
</cfquery>
<cfoutput query="texte">
    <cfset "#trim(label)#" = "#trim(content)#">
</cfoutput>
```

If I need a textblock I can then simply use the `label` like so:

```
<cfoutput>#tx_hello_world#</cfoutput>
```

My problem is with the 2nd table which contains a list of modules.

Each module has it's own description (headers, subheaders, info, bullets 1-5). I have to loop through all modules (25) so I just stored the `labels` in the database, hoping to do a single loop and output the `labels` from the database. Unfortunately outputting `label123` returns

```
 #label123#
```

vs me hoping for

```
 "text from table textblocks stored at label123"
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to store "dynamic variables" in MySQL and upon outputting these, retrieve the underlying value for them? If not, what is a better approach of outputting 25 modules in a single loop without saying "if this is module A, take text tx_module_a_title, else if ..."

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
So I'm hoping to avoid this having to run on every loop:

```
<cfif mods.module_name EQ "agents">
    <cfset variables.module_header = tx_module_b2b_agents_title>
    <cfset variables.module_subheader = tx_module_b2b_agents>
    <cfset variables.module_info = tx_module_b2b_agents_info>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_1 = tx_module_b2b_agn_accounts>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_2 = tx_module_b2b_agn_price_clients>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_3 = tx_module_b2b_agn_client_mgt>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_4 = tx_module_b2b_agn_create_retailer>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_5 = tx_module_b2b_exp_grace>
    <cfset variables.module_usage_tx = tx_vertreter/tx_gen_month>
<cfelseif mods.module_name EQ "preorder">
    <cfset variables.module_header = tx_module_b2b_preorder_title>
    <cfset variables.module_subheader = tx_module_b2b_preorder>
    <cfset variables.module_info = tx_module_b2b_preord_info>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_1 = tx_module_b2b_pre_split_type>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_2 = tx_module_b2b_pre_qty_y_n>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_3 = tx_module_b2b_pre_deliverydate>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_4 = tx_module_b2b_exp_grace>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_5 = "">
    <cfset variables.module_usage_tx = tx_gen_month >
<cfelseif mods.module_name EQ "export">
    <cfset variables.module_header = tx_module_b2b_export_title>
    <cfset variables.module_subheader = tx_module_b2b_export>
    <cfset variables.module_info = tx_module_b2b_export_info>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_1 = tx_module_b2b_exp_pricelists>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_2 = tx_module_b2b_exp_currencies>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_3 = tx_module_b2b_exp_customerlist>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_4 = tx_module_b2b_exp_regional_assortme>
    <cfset variables.module_bull_5 = tx_module_b2b_exp_grace>
    <cfset variables.module_usage_tx = tx_gen_month>
... 22 else-ifs to go
</cfif>
```

If I could store the textblock behind the `tx_` values in the database module record I could retrieve them from there.

Answer (score 1):

When you output the content from the db you can use `de()` and `evalaute()` on the content to process the vars. You will likely need to use a nested combination. I forget the exact syntax.
`De(evaluate('#var#'))` or something like that.

However this will prove problematic if you have any other `#` in the content that is not a var. I would suggest using lexicons instead. See this article [Content Management : Processing Dynamic Content](http://www.michaels.me.uk/post.cfm/content-management-processing-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your texte query has the variable content in it You can do:

```
<cfloopquery="texte">
    <cfset variables[trim(texte.label)] = trim(texte[content][texte.currentrow])>
</cfloop>
```

Your query is a structure that you can reference like another structure and you can use the built in currentrow attribute to reference the currentrow in the struture

After re-reading your question it looks like context is stored in the modules table? Then you could do. Either way you should try to avoid using evaluate whenever possible although that would work.

```
<cfloop query="texte">
  <cfloop query="modulesquery">
    <cfset variables[trim(texte.label)] = trim(modulesquery[content][modulesquery.currentrow])>
 </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: yeah, no friend of evaluate. Will try that, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna focus on this bit:

> Question: Is it possible to store "dynamic variables" in MySQL and
>   upon outputting these, retrieve the underlying value for them?

What I'd perhaps do is store the text as a file, and store the path to the file in the DB.  Then when you need to get CF to process the file - the only way your variables can be resolved - just pull the path from the DB, and include the file at that path.

If the text needs to go in the DB, then you're gonna need to read it out of the DB, write it to file, then include the file.  To process CF variables it needs to be processed by CF, and to do that, you need to pass a file to ColdFusion.  That's it.

However writing files all over the place and including them every time you need them is gonna be slow because the files need to be compiled before they're run, and the compilation process is comparatively slow.

The way around this is to only write the file when it changes, rather than every time it's needed.  On most websites the data is read orders of magnitude more frequently than it changes, just by the nature of how websites work.